# Struggling with Java assignment that reads name, age and height

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a java assignment for class. Very basic but just starting to learn programming. The main jist of the assignment is to write a Java program that reads a student name, his/her age, and his/her height (in feet) from the console and prints out all pieces of data related to a student on one line. This is what I have so far but I am getting a few errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Name = Mike;
        int age = 21;
        double height = 5.9;

        Scanner inReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Mike");

        Name = inReader.nextLine("Mike");

        System.out.print("21");

        age = inReader.nextInt("21");

        System.out.println("5.9");

        height = inReader.nextDouble ("5.9");

        System.out.println ("Mike" + "21" + "5.9");
    }

}
```

Comment: "This is what I have so far but I am getting a few errors." It would help if you said what those are.

Comment: Sorry. First error is that is that it does not like "String Name = Mike;" It is saying that cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: You probably mean `String Name = "Mike";`. Start at the first error, fix it, and continue down. Read the documentation of the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, paying particular attention to what parameters the methods take.

Comment: This is because strings in source code must be surrounded with double quotes, so "Mike" would do the magic

Comment: You have variables age and height, but you don't use them, why?  Move your System.out.println() to after the assignment, then display the variables.  "Mike" + "21" + "5.9" will result in Mike215.9

Comment: If the assignment is to read name, age and height from the console why are you setting this values with Mike, 21 and 5.9?

Comment: Yes that worked! I don't know how I missed that. the 2nd error I am seeing comes on "Name = inReader.nextLine("Mike");" ... It is saying the method nextLine() in the type scanner is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: You should also follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase; they start with lowercase. So `Name` should be `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are off track in a few ways.

1. `inReader.nextLine("Mike");` should be `inReader.nextLine();`. You cannot put something between those brackets in this case.
2. `String Name = Mike; int age = 21;double height = 5.9;` 
   just need to be declared. You want to enter the data in the console, not the code itself.
   `String Name; int age = 0;double height = 0;`
3. `System.out.println("Mike");` is not where you put inputs. Rather, it is where you put prompts that go to the user. You want to ask the user for their input there.
4. To print the variables in a string, you want to put the variable name in the string like so: `System.out.println (height);`

The full working code is below, but I encourage you to try and understand how this works. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Name;
        int age = 0;
        double height = 0;

        Scanner inReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is their name?");
        Name = inReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is their age?");
        age = inReader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is their height?");
        height = inReader.nextDouble ();
        System.out.println (Name + " " + age + " " + "  " + height);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I was reading on javatprint about the scanner package and that really helped!

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here ist a first solution to give you a starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name ;
    int age ;
    double height;

    Scanner inReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    name = inReader.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter age:");
    age = inReader.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter height");
    height = inReader.nextDouble();

    System.out.println ("name: " + name + ", age: " +age + ", height: " + height);
}
```

The above code will work as long as you enter valid input. Try it. Then input something invalid (for example a char for age)